# How to set BLOG_ADMIN_POST_FIELDSET_FILTER in djangocms_blog?

Tags: django-cms

I just came across [this part](https://djangocms-blog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/admin_customization.html#filter-function) of the djangocms_blog documentation that says:

> You can add / remove / filter fields at runtime by defining a method on you custom admin and proving its name in BLOG_ADMIN_POST_FIELDSET_FILTER.
>
> Function example:
>
> ```py
> def fieldset_filter_function(fsets, request, obj=None):
>     if request.user.groups.filter(name='Editor').exists():
>         fsets[1][1]['fields'][0].append('author')  # adding 'author' field if user is Editor
>     return fsets
> ```

I don't know what to put inside this `BLOG_ADMIN_POST_FIELDSET_FILTER` setting.

I tried to set it to those 2 values, but it's not working:

```py
BLOG_ADMIN_POST_FIELDSET_FILTER = "myapp.admin.custom_fieldset_filter_function"
BLOG_ADMIN_POST_FIELDSET_FILTER = "custom_fieldset_filter_function"
```

I came across the PR that added this features, and it seems to [only accept a `callable`](https://github.com/nephila/djangocms-blog/pull/180/files#diff-a38118a71aa2a2e8b78d4d20982674e98c0971291c29fb9afdafe776b74d8e01R113).

So I tried this:

```py
from myapp.admin import custom_fieldset_filter_function
BLOG_ADMIN_POST_FIELDSET_FILTER = custom_fieldset_filter_function
```

But I got this answer from my dev server:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
  File "/home/me/test-website/website/settings.py", line 254, in <module>
    from my_test_app.admin import custom_fieldset_filter_function
  File "/home/me/my-test-app/my_test_app/admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    import djangocms_blog.admin as blog_admin
  File "/home/me/test-website/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djangocms_blog/admin.py", line 4, in <module>
    from cms.admin.placeholderadmin import FrontendEditableAdminMixin, PlaceholderAdminMixin
[...]
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I don't know what to do in order to set this var to a callable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that the error was triggered while trying to import `djangocms_blog.admin`, and that this import has nothing to do with my custom fieldset filter function, but is related to other things in my `admin.py` code.

So I moved my `custom_fieldset_filter_function` *outside* of my `admin.py` file in order to stop the dependencies errors.

It now sits happily in a file named `update_fields.py`, and everything's working as expected.