# How to update djangocms-blog post extensions fields position?

Tags: django-cms

I have some post extensions adding new fields in my Posts objects.

I created the migration, launched my website, and I thought that maybe [customizing the fieldsets](https://djangocms-blog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/admin_customization.html#customizing-the-fieldsets) would allow me to customize the position of the post extensions fieldset too.

That didn't seems to be the case. I created a new `SmallIntegerField` named `my_new_field` in a `PostExtension` class that I registered using `blog_admin.register_extension(PostExtensionInline)` (I also created the `PostExtensionInline` class by following the [doc](https://djangocms-blog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/extensions.html)).

I added a breakpoint in my `update_fields` function that I'm using to update the order of the fields of my posts (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75212265/) and its answer for more infos on this), and I can't find any mention to `my_new_field` in the `fgets` arg:

```py
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
> /home/me/my-test-app/my_test_app/update_fields.py(3)update_fields()
-> return fsets
(Pdb) l
  1     def update_fields(fsets, request, obj):
  2         breakpoint()
  3  ->     return fsets
[EOF]
(Pdb) fsets
[(None, {'fields': ['title', 'subtitle', 'slug', 'publish', 'categories', 'abstract', 'sites', 'author']}), ('Info', {'fields': [['tags', 'related'], ['date_published', 'date_published_end', 'date_featured'], 'app_config', 'enable_comments'], 'classes': ('collapse',)}), ('Images', {'fields': [['main_image', 'main_image_thumbnail', 'main_image_full']], 'classes': ('collapse',)}), ('SEO', {'fields': [['meta_description', 'meta_title', 'meta_keywords']], 'classes': ('collapse',)})]
```

<s>How can I update my field position?</s> *(see edit below)*

---

*edit:* I can't think of a way to tweak the order of the post extension fields. But I realized that my real problem (yeah yeah that's a case of [XYproblem](https://xyproblem.info/)) is that I want conditional inline (only include the post extension for a certain apphook that's using a defined `BlogConfig` instance.

How to conditionally add the `inline` post extension form/fields to my admin create form based on the `BlogConfig` instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out (and it's not pretty, but it works).

I added those lines in my `admin.py`:

```py
# replace PostAdmin get_inlines function in order to hide event_date on regular blog posts
from djangocms_blog.admin import PostAdmin
from .misc import get_inline_instances as patched_get_inline_instances
PostAdmin.get_inline_instances = patched_get_inline_instances
```

And here's my code on `misc.py`:

```py
def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
    from djangocms_blog.cms_appconfig import BlogConfig
    from djangocms_blog.admin import PostAdmin
    from json import loads

    inline_instances = super(PostAdmin, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj)

    if "app_config" in request.GET:
        # get blog config instance from request
        blog_config = BlogConfig.objects.filter(pk=request.GET["app_config"])
        # get config from saved json
        config = loads(blog_config.values()[0]["app_data"])
        # get template_prefix from config

        if config:
            template_prefix = config['config']['template_prefix']
            if template_prefix == "djangocms_blog_agenda":
                return inline_instances
    return []
```

I used the `template_prefix` value in a `BlogConfig` instance of djangocms_blog to update the code based on the request:

- If we have "djangocms_blog_agenda" in the `template_prefix`, then return the inline instances.
- If we don't have this (default `BlogConfig`, another `BlogConfig` that do not need my current post extension fields), return an empty list.

The result can be viewed here:

[image: blog screenshot]

> Blog posts list screenshot, we can see that the articles are displayed by most recent "published date" first.

---

[image: select blog config screenshot]

> We can select our blog config after a click on "Blog > Add Post...".

---

[image: agenda screenshot]

> Agenda post creation screenshot, we can see that there's a post extension named "event date" (not present in Blog post creation screenshot).

---

[image: agenda list screenshot]

> Agenda list screenshot, we can see that the "events" are displayed by nearest future "event date" date.